# Global Validation Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Sonata admin bundle for one of my sites. I have set up few admin services and everything is going on fine. Now am stuck with the validation. I want the inputs fields to not accept scripts or invalid data. And I want this for all the fields. Is there a way to implement validation on a global basis..?? i.e for all the form fields? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use a custom validator service ....

Sonata documentation provides a example of how implement this :

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/conditional_validation.html